# How to determine the initial current directory when emacs is run from command line?

Tags: shell, environment

How can I determine (from within Emacs) the current directory as it was when the Shell launched `emacs` from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICT, Emacs does not save this info in a standard place.  Håkon's solution might work for you, but that completely depends on the program that launches Emacs: some will put the directory in $PWD, but others won't (so you may get a valid $PWD, or no $PWD, or a $PWD that's not truthful).  Other solutions would be:

- If it's for your own personal use, just add

  ```
  (setq my-saved-launch-directory default-directory)
  ```

  somewhere at the beginning of your `~/.emacs`, after which you can use that variable.
- Otherwise, you can use

  ```
  (with-current-buffer "*scratch*" default-directory)
  ```

  which will usually work as long as nothing has deleted `*scratch*` nor changed its default directory.  As pointed out by Gilles, you can also use the `*Messages*` buffer, which might even work better.

Comment: I think `*Messages*` is less likely to have its working directory changed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Section 38.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html) *"Operating System Environment"* in the GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual:

> **Variable: initial-environment** This variable holds the list of
>   environment variables Emacs inherited from its parent process when
>   Emacs started.

So you can scan the list and check for any item starting with `PWD=`. For example:

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun my--get-initial-pwd ()
  (let ((var) (value))
    (cl-dolist (str initial-environment)
      (when (string-match "^\\(.*?\\)=\\(.*\\)" str)
        (setq var (match-string 1 str))
        (setq value (match-string 2 str))
        (when (string= var "PWD")
          (cl-return))))
    value))
```

Comment: You can use `getenv-internal` instead of writing out the scanning loop.